# How to restart gunicorn in Jenkins build?

Tags: nginx, django, jenkins, gunicorn

I'm trying to build a Jenkins job that (1) pulls the latest from `Git`, (2) builds my `Django` project, and (3) restarts `gunicorn` and `nginx`.

However, when I try to restart `gunicorn`, I get the following error:

```
jenkins@digitalocean:/$ /usr/sbin/service gunicorn restart 
Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Access denied
```

I think this is because the user `jenkins` doesn't have access to `gunicorn.service`? What are some strategies I can use to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said previously, your jenkins user simply doesn't have the permissions to restart the gunicorn process.

You can in fact give it sudo rights, but another solution is to use **virtualenv** to isolate your Python application environnement. This way the virtualenv can belong to jenkins user, the process too, and he can restart it.

Answer (score 0):

1. hint: it's in [The `/usr/sbin` Directory](http://www.linfo.org/usr_sbin.html).

   > The `/usr/sbin` directory contains non-vital system utilities that are
   >   used after booting (i.e., starting the system) by the system
   >   administrator.
2. hint: it's a [**service**](https://www.linux.com/news/introduction-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts).
3. hint: You got `Access denied`

Hat-trick! We have [`sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws) for these situations.

```
sudo service gunicorn restart
```

Comment: Since the jenkins user probably doesn't have permission to sudo, you might need to give it permission to run the service command with it. See, for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service

Comment: The jenkins user doesn't have permissin to sudo. I'm still trying to make it work, and I'll try your link, Matt. Thanks!